# SQL запрос по двум условиям

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо узнать количество участников (Фамилия + Имя), которые получили по русскому языку и математике двойки.

В нашем случае это количество равно **2**.

Как составить SQL-запрос для такой выборки? 
Чтобы как-то выйти из ситуацию я проделал несколько запросов с помощью **EXCEPT**. Думаю должен быть какой-то более быстрый способ.

Comment: *количество участников (Фамилия + Имя)* — это ведь взаимоисключающие требования: получить *и* количество *и* фамилию+имя.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я так понимаю, что (Фамилия + Имя) это идентификатор участника, а не то, что нужно выбрать.

Comment: Скажет тогда по другому. Получить Фамилия+Имя у которых Оценка и по русскому и по математике равно 2.

Comment: Да - Фамилия + Имя это ключ

Comment: может стоить немного изменить структуру? в плане для предметов завести справочник, учеников сделать тоже справочником, иначе при такой структуре возможны опечатки которые приведут к не корректным результатам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сджойним саму на себя и ограничим условиями:

```
select
    m_rus.lastname,
    m_rus.firstname
from marks m_rus
join marks m_mat on m_rus.lastname=m_mat.lastname
    and m_rus.firstname=m_mat.firstname and m_mat.discipline='Математика'
where m_rus.discipline='Русский язык' and m_rus.mark=2 and m_mat.mark=2`
```

Answer (score 1):

Способ, похожий что указал null, но покороче:

```
SELECT count (student_id)
FROM  tbl WHERE [Предмет] IN ('Русский язык', 'Математика') AND [Оценка] = 2
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING  (COUNT(*) = 2)
```

В IN указываете интересующие Вас предметы.

COUNT(*) = количество аргументов в IN.

Если не сработает, то можно изменить: having count(distinct student_id) = 2

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.[Инициалы]
from 
(select [Имя] + ' ' + [Фамилия] as [Инициалы], [Предмет], [Оценка] from Table) t
where [Оценка] = 2
and ([Предмет] = 'Русский язык' or [Предмет] = 'Математика')
group by [Инициалы]
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Нужно дополнить условием по предметам - нигде не сказано, что у нас есть только математика и русский язык.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы - нужно учитывать все ситуации. Хотя о существовании других предметов нигде оговорок не было.